# Objectify/Datastore - transaction inside a transaction

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

What happens if you put a transaction inside a transaction in objectify/datastore? What is the order of execution and how do things resolve?

For example,

**1) If the inner transaction fails, will the outer transaction also fail?**

**2) If the outer transaction fails, will the inner transaction be rolled back if it happened to finish?**

```
// Outer Transaction
Thing th = ofy().transact(() -> {
    Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
    thing.modify();
    ofy().save().entity(thing);


    // Inner Transaction
    // This transaction could be in another method used in various other places
    Thing th2 = ofy().transact(() -> {
        Thing thing2 = ofy().load().key(thingKey2).now();
        thing2.modify();
        Thing thing2 = ofy().load().key(thingKey3).now();
        thing3.modify();
        ofy().save().entity(thing2);
        ofy().save().entity(thing3);
        return thing;
    });

    return thing;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is extensive documentation about this here:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions

What question do you want to ask that isn't answered there?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Your question seems to be answered by https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions#transaction-inheritance .  The inner transact() call adds the new modifications to the current transaction.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can nest a `ofy().transactNew()` inside of a `ofy().transact()` to suspend the outer transaction until the new one is done?

Comment: You are correct.